# In C# what does this code with "get" mean?

Tags: c#, properties

I am new to C#.

```
private string m;
public string M { get { return m; } }
```

Is this kind of a getter/setter in C# like Java?

Comment: It's called a property. This one is readonly and thus corresponds to a simple getter in java. If it had a `set` method it'd correspond to a getter setter pair.

Comment: Yes it's a getter (ReadOnly-Property in c#).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This part is a field:

```
private string m;
```

This part is a read-only property that returns the value of the `m` field:

```
public string M { get { return m; } }
```

You could make this a read-write property like so:

```
public string M {
    get { return m; }
    set { m = value; }
}
```

Or you could have more complex logic in there:

```
public string M {
    get {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m))
            return "m is null or empty";
        return m;
    }
}
```

Basically, fields are only good at holding things, while properties are more like methods and can introduce logic.

Comment: @David - In classes, fields are generally private and accessed via public properties, where needed. This isn't always the case. There are also structs, which are different and often have public fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
private string m;
```

First, you create a new string variable with private modifier. If this in class, then it's not visible outside of this class.

```
public string M { get { return m; } }
```

Then you create a property of that string variable. This property is read-only and then you can access this variable outside of class where you created this variable. You cannot assign values to this variable with this type of property.

Answer (score 1):

It's a public readonly [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), i.e.: it only has a public `get` accessor. [Auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) can achieve the same effect with less code:

```
public string M { get; private set; }
```

This propery has a public `get` but a *private* `set`. The CLR actually generates an `m`-like [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) for storing the value... but it's hidden.

Answer (score 0):

It's a getter. There is no publically accessible setter, so m must be set elsewhere in the class.

Answer (score 0):

This is for defining Readonly properties in C#, here you only have a getter

Answer (score 0):

It is a public getter for m, but it lets you call it like it was a variable for example

```
string s = M;
```

which would make `s == m`

Answer (score 0):

This is what is called a property in C#. It is accessed as if it was a member variable, but the `get` method is called instead. Properties can also have a `set` method, to make them modifiable.

Answer (score 0):

The first line is called a field. It will create a private (i.e. accessible only within the class) member variable named `m`.

The second line is called a property. This particular property wraps the field `m` and is read-only (i.e. it has a `get` but no `set`).

Properties in C# are accessed as if they are fields, like so:

```
obj.SomeProp = "Some value";
string val = obj.SomeProp;
```

However, properties can be implemented with more complexity than just getting and setting a field. The body of the property is like a method. It can contain non-trivial code.