# What is the meaning of "get"?

Tags: c#, properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C# what does this code with “get” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945855/in-c-sharp-what-does-this-code-with-get-mean)

I'm using open source project. In this project there is function.

```
public virtual ICollection<Customer> AffiliatedCustomers 
{
    get
    {
         return _affiliatedCustomers ?? (_affiliatedCustomers = new List<Customer>()); 
    }
    protected set { _affiliatedCustomers = value; }
 }
```

I don't understand what is the meaning of "get".
Can you please explain this function.

Answer (score 8):

`AffiliatedCustomers` is a *property*.

The `get` defines the property getter, which is a method used internally to return the value by the property.  It allows you to use this given an instance of the class like so:

```
var customers = theClass.AffiliatedCustomers; // Looks like a field, but is a property
```

Properties can also have a `set` section, as well, as this one does (`protected set { _affiliatedCustomers = value; }`), which gives you control over what happens when you set the value via the Property.

For details, see [Properties in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

This is not a function. It is a property. A property is basically a fancy wrapper for some variable. For example, declaring the following property:

```
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

will actually compile to something like this:

```
private string backing_SomeProperty;

public void set_SomeProperty(string value)
{
    backing_SomeProperty = value;
}

public int get_SomeProperty()
{
    return backing_SomeProperty;
}
```

That's an example of an *automatic* property. Of course, you can also define the getter and setter methods yourself like this:

```
public string SomeProperty
{
    get
    {
        // some logic code here
        // then return some value
    }

    set
    {
        // some logic code here
        // then set some value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a property,
 Quoted by msdn:

> Properties are members that provide a flexible mechanism to read, write, or compute the values of private fields. Properties can be used as though they are public data members, but they are actually special methods called accessors. This enables data to be accessed easily while still providing the safety and flexibility of methods.

Please refer to this link for more:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Properties have a getter and a setter - their purpose is obvious (to get and set the value of the property).

When you use auto properties, there is still a `get` and a `set`, but the backing variable is automatically implemented for you. In the example you have given the author of the code has chosen to have their own implementation of the `get` - in this case to automatically initialise the member variable the first time the property is accessed.